# Growth of functions (Discrete math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

a) Show that $ \frac{x^3 + 2x}{2x+1} \; is \; O(x^2) $

b) Find witnesses $ C \; and\; K $

My answer was :

$ x^3 + 2x \le c(x^2)(2x+1) $

$ x^3 \le c(x^2)(2x+1) , \; when \;c=1 , x>1 $

$ 2x \le c(x^2)(2x+1) , when \; c=1 , x>1 $

$ so \frac{x^3+2x}{2x+1} \le cx^2 , when \; c=2 \;and\; k=1 $

Is my answer correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The order of your inequalities isn't very suggestive of what steps you are taking or why these inequalities might be true (how did you convince yourself that they were true?).  But everything you wrote appears to be correct.

Comment: I was just checking. That question was on my quiz and the instructor said that c is 3/2 or 2/3 something like that. Also when we got our papers back, some students wrote the same witnesses as me and they didn't got the full mark and i got the full mark. Is it about the proof or what is it ?